# Appium wait for specific log

Tags: java, android, logging, automation, appium

I'm trying to wait for certain log to appear and then do some method.
I know that Appium can wait for elements to appear in the screen, I want to know if I can wait for log to appear from "logcat".

Thank you.

**edited:** I Implemented 3 methods and **IT WORKS FOR ME**:

```
public String WaitTillLogAppearInLogcat(String i_Log, int timeOutSeconds){
    String log = null;
    LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    while(log == null && ((Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toMillis() / 1000) < timeOutSeconds)) {
        CollectLogs();
        log = GetLogLineFromCollectedLogs(i_Log);
        endTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
    return log;
}

public void CollectLogs(){
    List<LogEntry> entireLogBuffer = androidDriver.manage().logs().get("logcat").getAll();
    for(LogEntry LogLine : entireLogBuffer) {
        launcherLogs += LogLine.getMessage();
        launcherLogs += "\n";
    }
}


public String GetLogLineFromCollectedLogs(String logContent) {
    String LogInCollectedLogs = null;
    String[] lines = launcherLogs.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (line.contains(logContent)){
            LogInCollectedLogs = line;
        }
    }
    return LogInCollectedLogs;
}
```

Where launcherLogs is String data member of the using class,
and androidDriver is the Appium driver.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/logs/get-log/)? Consider using that and checking what log you got.

Comment: @tomerpacific Yes. I want to listen to specific log. When getting the log I have been waiting for, do specific method.

Comment: you cannot wait for log to appear in logcat, what you can do is clear old log and perform certain action and check for the new log.